# How to send an HTTP Post to a URL from a VG-IDMS

Tags: http, db2, cobol, mainframe

Does someone knows a way of sending an HTTP post to a URL from a VG-IDMS program?

We have a mainframe database with a few programs written on it and we have so far successfully created functionality for it to work as a kinda web service provider, responding to HTTP get requests with XML data. That way we've been able to create external (and modernized) apps that requests data from it as if would be a modern server.

Now we'd like to make the opposite. We want certain VG programs to create and send HTTP post requests to an external URL (most likely JSON formatted although not important). The objective is to create some sort of notification so that when certain events happen on the mainframe (say data got updated) a VG program would notify an external web service (or web api) of it.

I've been trying to find documentation all over but failed so far.

**EDIT:** Replacing the old mainframe is not an option for now

Comment: You might wnat to take a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.hali001/cc.htm and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011917/how-can-z-os-call-a-web-service